# How to avoid that Facebook fetches some images of my website?

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, fetch

I´m having problems with my cutenews and Facebook "share" buttons, but I´m working with "og:" metas to solve it.

In the mean time, another problem that I have (and I won´t solve it with Open Graph Protocol) it´s that some images are always fetched by Facebook and the most important images (the articles images) too but there isn´t the first choices.

So, if Facebook fetches 7 images, the first 3 options to people are always the banners images and not the articles images.

Is there any way to mark the images that I don´t want to be fetched by Google?

Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already implemented the proper Open Graph tags (og:image, etc), then the next step is to determine if your implementation of those tags is valid.

Facebook provides an [Open Graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) for exactly this purpose. Provide it with the URL in question, and it will tell you what to do next.